# Lambda CloudWatch Log : Logger doesn't log, but print works

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

### Problem

I cannot use my logger to log to the console.
Is this because logging requires writing the contents of the log to a file, which Lambda cannot do, because it's a function invocation ? Can we not use the CloudWatch Log as the "file".

##### Clarifications

- `Lambda` has the permission to write into `CloudWatch` via the basic `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy

*I am using terms such as "file", function invocation loosely*. Please critique freely.

#### Code I tested on

```
import logging
import os
import json
import boto3
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

IP_COUNT_TABLE = os.getenv("AWS_IP_COUNT_TABLE", "ip-tracking-list")
DENIED_IP_TABLE = os.getenv("AWS_DENIED_IP_TABLE", "ip-denied-list")
PROCESSED_EVENTS_TABLE = os.getenv("AWS_PROCESSED_EVENTS_TABLE", "cloudwatch-my-logs")
HTTP_REQUEST_HEADER_TO_CHECK = os.getenv("HTTP_REQUEST_HEADER_TO_CHECK", "some.endpoint.com")

# Initialize DynamoDB client
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ip_count_table = dynamodb.Table(IP_COUNT_TABLE)
    denied_ip_table = dynamodb.Table(DENIED_IP_TABLE)
    processed_events_table = dynamodb.Table(PROCESSED_EVENTS_TABLE)

    ip_count = defaultdict(int)

    try:
        logger.info(f"Processing event: {event}")
        print(f"Processing event: {event}")
        for record in event.get('logEvents', []):
            event_id = record.get('id', '')
            message = record.get('message', {})
            if not event_id:
                logger.error("No timestamp found in log event")
                continue

            if check_event_processed(str(event_id), processed_events_table):
                continue

            if 'httpRequest' in message and 'headers' in message['httpRequest']:
                for header in message['httpRequest']['headers']:
                    if header['name'].lower() == 'host' and header['value'] == HTTP_REQUEST_HEADER_TO_CHECK:
                        ip_address = message['httpRequest']['clientIp']
                        timestamp = convert_to_iso_format(message['timestamp'])
                        ip_count[ip_address] += 1
                        break

            mark_event_as_processed(str(event_id), processed_events_table)

        if len(ip_count) == 0:
            logger.info(f"No IP addresses to process")
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps('No IP addresses to process')
            }

        # Batch update IP counts and check the deny list
        for ip, count in ip_count.items():
            update_ip_count(ip, timestamp, ip_count_table, count)

        check_and_add_to_denied_list(ip_count_table, denied_ip_table)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error processing event record: {e}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps('Error processing logs')
        }

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('IP addresses processed')
    }
```

#### Goal

Trying to understand why this doesn't work and how to properly set up my AWS Lambda for unit tests. Printing a statement is a sanity check tool.

Comment: Lambda can write into cloudwatch logs. Can you check if your lambda has the permission to write into cloudwatch ?  The basic 'AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole' policy will give the permission to your lambda to write into cloudwatch.

Comment: I do have the 'AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole' policy. It's just that I cannot use `logger`, but I can use the `print` statement. Is there a deeper technical reason for this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html#python-logging-lib), you should be able to use the logger library. As logging for INFO level is disabled by default you should change it. However, you should use `setLevel` of logger to achieve it and not `basicConfig`. The doc above has the basic example in it.

Comment: Crisp answer. Thank you!